# How come OpenGL version is only 1.4 with Tesla K40?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, opengl

I need to develop for OpenGL 2.0.

Running `glxinfo | grep "OpenGL version"` I get:

```
OpenGL version string: 1.4 (2.1 Mesa 17.0.1)
```

#### Edit - Full output:

https://pastebin.com/Up6bwpq5

I'm running on a server with 2 *Tesla K40*, which are quiet new (and expensive) as far as I know, and according to the [CNET spec](https://www.cnet.com/products/nvidia-tesla-k40-gpu-computing-processor-teslak40-12-gb-00yl376/specs/)
 should support OpenGL 4.0 (unless I got this wrong).

- Nvidia-version: 390.12
- OS: Ubuntu 16.0.4

Any idea what I'm missing here?

Comment: @dsstorefile I see all the k40 series listed here: http://www.nvidia.com/download/driverResults.aspx/132547/en-us

Comment: @dsstorefile I see... let me check.

Comment: @dsstorefile Unfortunately getting the same results with http://www.nvidia.com/download/driverResults.aspx/132541/en-us. Perhaps it's something with the mesa version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you connected from the console or remote shell? 
That is the typical output when you are in by remote.

If that's the case, unless you are using a very old release of Ubuntu you will face with this problem because of the newer Xorg. To be able to use higher OpenGL I'm afraid you have to go with something like VirtualGL (this requires you have a working X on the server though).

Comment: Yes that's exactly the case!

Comment: so, unless you are using a very old release of Ubuntu you will face with this problem because of the newer Xorg. To be able to use higher OpenGL I'm afraid you have to go with something like  VirtualGL (this requires you have a working X on the server though).